Is there a software I can use that will construct a chess game based on a specific order of captures?
I need to construct a game, whereby certain chess pieces get taken off the board in a specific order. I have tried ChatGPT to no avail, so I am wondering if there is any other kind of AI software available to do this.

Can you explain more about what you want the input and output to be? e.g. are you giving it a list like "white king takes black's white-square bishop; black knight takes white's e-pawn", or what?

Definitely don't use ChatGPT for anything chess-related. I don't think anyone has bothered developing a software this specific, but if you give us the details I don't think it'd be hard to build it manually.

Hi, thanks for your responses. I don't need to specify which piece takes which piece, until the end, when I need it to be the white queen that puts the black king in checkmate. I need the pieces to be captured in this order: White pawn, Black pawn Black pawn, Black knight, White pawn, White pawn, Black knight, Black pawn, Black pawn, Black bishop, White rook, Black rook, White pawn, Black rook, White bishop, Black king (checkmate by white queen) If you could build it manually, that would be amazing!

From what you have specified, it sounds as if one might construct such a game manually without much difficulty. If there's additional structure that makes it harder, then the best starting point might be the constraint feature in Jacobi chess engine: https://wismuth.com/jacobi/latest/solver.html#/jacobi/v0.7.5/doc.html
It doesn't directly allow to order captures, but it does allow you to describe in great detail the journey of individual pieces.

To search for a specific sequence of captures in a game that has already occurred you can use something like Chess Query Language.
The sequence of captures in your comment starting with White Pawn, Black pawn Black pawn, Black knight...  is nonsensical. It's unclear what this notation means, and it is impossible for three captures in a row happen to black pieces.

It's not impossible and not unclear. I mean, White wins the game, so it's not surprising that Black loses more pieces. It wouldn't be a grandmaster-level game or anything.
